# What is the relation of parametricity and function extensionality?

Tags: type-theory, parametricity, logical-relations

In Agda function extensionality can be defined like this:
`funExt = {A : Set} {B : Set} {f1 f2 : A → B} → (∀ x1 x2 → x1 ≡ x2 -> f1 x1 ≡ f2 x2) → f1 ≡ f2`
One may note a similarity in the definition of a (binary) logical relation
`f1 [A -> B] f2` being:
`∀ x1 x2 → x1 [A] x2 -> f1 x1 [B] f2 x2`.

What is the relation of logical relations to function extensionality?
Is there perhaps a relation to eta-equality?

Comment: Might be relevant, since Univalence implies extensionality: https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.05027

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there is a similarity in these two definitions.

Function extensionality that you showed is just a condition that specifies when two functions are equal.

If we talk about logical relations then a relation between two functions of types $A \to B$ does not necessarily have to express equality between two functions. But the equality relation is a possible binary relation between functions. Let us see how we can formulate a logical relation that specifies that two functions (both of type $A \to B$) are equal.

Denote by $A \leftrightarrow B$ the type of relations between values of types $A$ and $B$. The identity relation for the type $A$ is denoted by $[\textrm{id}^A]: A \leftrightarrow A$.

The logical relation for the extensional equality is formulated like this: Two functions are equal when they are in the identity relation for the type $A \to B$. That identity relation is denoted by $[\textrm{id}^{A \to B}]$. Then we can rewrite the Agda definition of the extensional equality in the language of relations like this:

$f_1\, [\textrm{id}^{A \to B}]\, f_2$ means $\forall x_1,\, x_2$ if $ x_1 \,[\textrm{id}^{A}]\, x_2$ then $f_1 (x_1) \,[\textrm{id}^{B}]\, f_2 (x_2)$

Now we can further rewrite this definition via the function-type construction for relations. The function-type construction is defined like this: Given any two relations $[r] : A \leftrightarrow B$  and $[s]:C\leftrightarrow D $, we can define the relation $[r\to s]: (A \to C)  \leftrightarrow (B \to D)$ by the formula similar to what you wrote: for any two functions $f: A\to C$ and $g: B\to D$, we have:

$f\, [r\to s]\, g$ means $\forall x:A,\, y:B$, if $ x \,[r]\, y$ then $f(x) \,[s]\, g(y)$

Now if we set $A=B$, $C = D$, $[r] = [\textrm{id}^A]$, and $[s] = [\textrm{id}^C]$, then we will get: $[r \to s] = [\textrm{id}^{A\to C}]$. So, the identity relation on functions is obtained by the function-type construction from identity relations on types `A` and `B`. That's all it seems to be.

Comment: This answer is totally correct, but let me add one additional comment. Parametric models satisfy the *identity extension property*: if $A[a]$ is a type with a free variable $a$, and $\mathsf{Id}_X$ is the identity relation for $X$, then $[\![ A[a] ]\!] (\mathsf{Id}_X/a) = \mathsf{Id}_{A[X]}$. This forces all parametric models to satisfy the condition above.

Comment: @NeelKrishnaswami It is hard for me to follow the notation in your comment. I will revise my answer a bit. I think the main point is that we must show a proof that `[A -> B] = id` follows from `[A] = id` and `[B]  = id`, it does not follow automatically.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't think my commented warranted a whole new answer, but comments make it hard to use rich notation...

Comment: @NeelKrishnaswami I have rewritten my answer and introduced new notation. I showed the derivation now. I'm not an expert in programming language theory, and I don't really understand the notation or the substance of what's going on in Reynolds's papers. For example, you said that "parametric models" will satisfy the "identity extension lemma". I think a practical programmer will not need to worry about the details of the models of the programming language. A programmer would never expect the programming language to implement a model that doesn't satisfy the identity extension lemma.